# Cómo hacer esta consulta con Eloquent en Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola amigos necesito de su ayuda, cómo haría esta consulta usando eloquent.

```
select p.*,c.name from categories c,peliculas p,category_pelicula pc
where pc.category_id='$id' and pc.category_id=c.id and pc.pelicula_id=p.id"
```

Estos son los modelos:

```
class Pelicula extends Model{
protected $fillable = [
    'title','description','year','linkView','linkDownload','image'
];
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->select('id','name');
    }
}

class Category extends Model{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','description'
    ];

    public function pelicula(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Pelicula::class);
    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano, por su ayuda.

Comment: si en los modelos están definidas la relaciones, en el caso del modelo categoria esta la relación pelicula (belongsToMany) y en el modelo pelicula esta la relación categoría (belongsToMany)

Comment: gracias, por la recomendación.

Answer (score 0):

Mas allá de que tienes las relaciones de Eloquent definidas, mi respuesta se basa en lo siguiente:

```
    return Category::select('category.name', 'peliculas.*')
                     ->join('category_pelicula', 'category.id', '=', 'category_pelicula.pelicula_id')
                     ->join('peliculas', 'peliculas.id', '=', 'category_pelicula.pelicula_id')
                    ->get();
```

Mi propuesta es:

- Usa el modelo `Category` para hacer el `join` explícito
- Usa un `join` para relacionar la tabla *pivot* `category_pelicula` con la tabla `category` por sus llaves primarias y foráneas
- Usa el segundo `join` para relacionar la tabla `peliculas` con la tabla *pivot* `category_pelicula`
- Mas allá de que tu consulta es funcional, considera usar los *joins explícitos* en vez de la sintaxis que estas manejando

**Aunque claramente esto también se puede llegar a lograr con las relaciones de `Eloquent`**

Answer (score 0):

`belongsToMany` es la solucion, la relacion entre **categoria** y **peliculas** es de muchas a muchas entonces tu modelo pelicula quedaria asi:

```
class Pelicula extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title','description','year','linkView','linkDownload','image'
    ];
    public function categorias(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_pelicula','pelicula_id','category_id');
    }
}
```

De similar forma tu modelo categoria:

```
class Category extends Model{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','description'
    ];

    public function peliculas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Pelicula::class,'category_pelicula','category_id','pelicula_id');
    }

}
```

Y luego solo debes utilizar ORM para la consulta:

```
$categoria=App\Categoria::with("peliculas")->find($id);
```

Ahora el acceso a los datos:

```
$nombre_de_categoria=$categoria->name;
//peliculas de dicha categoria:
foreach($categoria->peliculas as $pelicula){
  $titulo=$pelicula->title;
  $descripcion=$pelicula->description;
}
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

ya logre resolver esa consulta, lo hice con join como lo indicaron,  claro los modelos estan relacionados con belongsToMany.